# Inequality in a Hilbert Space: $\sup_{||f||_{2}\leq 1}||fg||_{2}\leq C ||g||_{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces

Let $f,g \in L^2(0,1)$ My question is the following: is there a constant $C>0$ such that
$$\sup_{||f||_{2}\leq 1}||fg||_{2}\leq C ||g||_{2},$$
all I know is that we have
$$\sup_{||f||_{2}\leq 1}<f.g>\leq C ||g||_{2},$$
using cauchy schwarz inequality.

Comment: I don't think so, since it would be possible to have $fg\in L^1(0,1)\setminus L^2(0,1)$. For example $f=g=1/\sqrt[4]{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, setting $f=g=\epsilon x^{-1/4}$ we have $\|f\|_2\ll 1$ for $\epsilon\ll 1$ but $$\|fg\|_{L^2} = \infty$$